# How can I use useAmp on Next.js 13 app router

Tags: next.js13, app-router

I was working on a Nextjs 13 with app router project. I want to make the website faster. I've come up with a solution called useAmp hook. But the problem here is, as long I know, it only works on page router. How can I make it work on app router?

I tried server-side fetching to make the website faster but it would be better if I could use that useAmp.